# Promtail parse log

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I am leaning to use loki，but why i can not received log like
`2023-09-01 10:10:13.678  INFO 13960 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.lson.test.admin.Starter              : hahhahahahha`

loki log show total_bytes=0B

```
level=info ts=2023-09-07T03:15:22.495330892Z caller=metrics.go:152 component=querier org_id=fake latency=fast query="{job=\"lson\"}" query_hash=1413285407 query_type=limited range_type=range length=14m37.507835166s start_delta=1h0m0.00315818s end_delta=45m22.495323188s step=14s duration=282.734µs status=200 limit=100 returned_lines=0 throughput=0B total_bytes=0B lines_per_second=0 total_lines=0 total_entries=0 store_chunks_download_time=0s queue_time=18.211µs splits=0 shards=0 cache_chunk_req=0 cache_chunk_hit=0 cache_chunk_bytes_stored=0 cache_chunk_bytes_fetched=0 cache_chunk_download_time=0s cache_index_req=0 cache_index_hit=0 cache_index_download_time=0s cache_result_req=0 cache_result_hit=0 cache_result_download_time=0s
```

loik and promtail version is 2.8.4

I think pipeline_stages.output if not define,it will send original log content to loki

promtail.yaml

```
server:
  # The HTTP port on which Promtail listens
  http_listen_port: 9080
  # The gRPC port to listen on. It's set to 0 here, so gRPC won't be enabled.
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  # The file used by Promtail to track which logs have been read to prevent re-reading on restart
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  # The address of the Loki instance where Promtail sends logs
  - url: http://192.168.10.45:3200/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: system
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          # Target hostname. This is a label; setting it to 192.168.10.45 doesn't mean logs will be fetched from that host. It's just a label.
          - localhost
        labels:
          # Labels added to the logs
          job: flink_log
          # Specifies where to collect logs from. This will match all files under /home/hubo/flink-1.17.1/logs/
          __path__: /home/hubo/flink-1.17.1/log/*
    pipeline_stages:
      - regex:
          expression: '^(?P<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})'
      - timestamp:
          source: timestamp
          format: '2006-01-02 15:04:05.000'
```

Comment: This can happen due to anyone many reasons: wrong job name in you query, wrong time interval, promtail didn't find log, prom tail didn't push the log, problem while promtail parsed log, promtail died before log occurred, etc.